# Selecting category from drop down populating same result with in all table elements ajax and jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I have used add new button with my code which is used to add blank elements to table.Now in first select drop down while selecting any element from drop down i want to populate relevant data to table but currently while selecting any element from select drop down it populate relevant data to all added element with in table.

view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>
    <!-- start: Content -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

          <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="wizard2" class="wizard-type2">
              <ul class="steps">
                <li class=""><a class="c-detail" href="form-wizard.html#tab21" data-toggle="tab">Articles</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="text-center">
                <h4 class="c-detail">Articles</h4>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="progress thin">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
</div>
</div> -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab21">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered datatable" id="records_table">

                      <thead>
                        <tr>

                          <th>Article Name</th>
                          <th>Article Number</th>
                          <th>Article Price</th>
                          <th>ArticleLedger</th>
                          <th>Remove</th>

                        </tr>

                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <button class="btn-info btn-sm add_new" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                        <tr id="trId1">
                          <td class="clone">
                            <select class="form-control InvoiceTypeClass" name="InvoiceTypeId" Id="InvoiceTypeId">
                              <option >Please select</option>                                                                                          
                              <% article.forEach(function(articletype) { %>
                                <option value=  "<%=articletype.ArticleName%>"><%=articletype.ArticleName%></option>
                                  <% }); %>
                                    </select>
                          </td>
                          <td><span class="addvalue"></span></td>
                          <td><span class="addvalue3"></span></td>
                          <td><span class="addvalue4"></span></td>
                          <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="del" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</button>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

ajax and jquery code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#dateof").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      format: "DD-MM-YYYY"
    });

    $("#dateto").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });

    $("#endDate").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });

    $("#created").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });

</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('data').on('change', function() {;

      var invoice_id = $(this).attr('attr_id');
      alert(invoice_id)
      $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/invoice/delete/' + invoice_id,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          invoice_id: invoice_id
        },
        success: function(response) {

          window.location.href = '/admin/invoice/'
        },
        error: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

      })
    });

  });

</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("change", ".InvoiceTypeClass", function() {
      var companyname = $(this).val();
      alert(companyname);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/invoice/getarticle/' + companyname,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          companyname: companyname
        },
        success: function(data) {
          data.forEach(function(item) {
            $('.addvalue').text(item.ArticleNumber);
            $('.addvalue3').text(item.ArticlePrice);
            $('.addvalue4').text(item.ArticleLedger);
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    });

    /********clone table row start*******/

    $(".add_new").click(function() {
      var clone = $(".odd:eq(0)").clone();
      $(".odd:last").after(clone).add;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.del', function() {
      if ($('.rows').length > 1) $(this).closest('.rows').remove();
    })
    /********clone table row End*******/
  });

</script>
```